# Paypal integration - GetExpressCheckout

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm working on PayPal integration (Express Checkout) using SOAP API. After DoExpressCheckout call I call GetExpressCheckoutDetails. In docs I found that the checkout status can be one of the following

- PaymentActionNotInitiated
- PaymentActionFailed
- PaymentActionInProgress
- PaymentCompleted

But docs do not actually say what does each of them mean. I understand all but PaymentActionInProgress - how do I handle it? Does it mean that I'll receive IPN call from PayPal when it's completed? Also, can I simulate this response for testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello Alex Buynyachenko,

A value of PaymentActionNotInitiated occurs when you submit a GetExpressCheckoutDetails API call before the buyer logs into a PayPal account or when they log into their account, return to your website but have not completed the payment yet.

PaymentActionFailed occurs when you've tried to complete the payment but it failed for some reason. The error response information returned would have details on the failure.

PaymentActionInProgress this is returned when you submit the DoExpressCheckoutPayment API call but haven't received a response yet - you shouldn't encounter that one often.

PaymentCompleted is returned after you get a successful DoExpressCheckoutPayment response. I just tested submitting an Authorization to see if I would get "InProgress" or "Completed" and I received a "Completed" value back.

Comment: Should a person check the latest `CHECKOUTSTATUS` of GetExpressCheckoutDetails for `PaymentActionNotInitiated` before running DoExpressCheckout as anything else indicates a failed, pending, or completed transaction?

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. Step-1: when I run this below code then it returned  [CHECKOUTSTATUS] => PaymentActionNotInitiated

    $padata                 =   '&TOKEN='.urlencode(_GET('token'));
    $httpParsedResponseAr   = $this->PPHttpPost('GetExpressCheckoutDetails', $padata, PPL_API_USER, PPL_API_PASSWORD, PPL_API_SIGNATURE, PPL_MODE);

 2. Step-2: Second time when I run this below code then it returned me [CHECKOUTSTATUS] => PaymentActionCompleted

$httpResDoExpChkPay = $this->PPHttpPost('DoExpressCheckoutPayment', $padata);

I think it will help you to better understand.
```